# CEF spams a lot of the same type of errors errors in c++ implementation in the game

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I implemented cef into the game so that the browser could be displayed in it. But all the files were in the folder with the game, after I removed all the files and dll from the game and set up new paths, my cef started giving the following errors to the console

```
[0719/191202.173:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
[0719/191202.243:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(975)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515
[0719/191202.243:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
[0719/191202.420:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(975)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515
[0719/191202.420:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)
[0719/191202.493:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(975)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515
[0719/191202.493:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 4 time(s)
[0719/191202.636:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(975)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515
[0719/191202.636:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 5 time(s)
[0719/191202.700:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(975)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515
[0719/191202.700:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 6 time(s)
```

and so it outputs these errors indefinitely.
i use cef with c++ implementation.

I definitely didn't change anything in the files associated with the cef, I tried to configure the paths to the subprocess, etc., everything is configured correctly, but errors still occur. What are your versions, what could be the problem?

Comment: -1073741515 (or C0000135 in hex) means 'DLL not found'. What DLL I have no idea although maybe it's the DLL you said you removed.

Comment: thx i'll check in dependency walker the necessary dll

Comment: btw where i can check error codes? and how can I understand which dll is missing? I tried looking through dependency walker but didn't find a problem

Comment: I checked how many dlls are loaded and found out that the same amount is loaded in both cases, so that's not the problem

Comment: @noob_proger: You can look up the error codes directly in [`ntstatus.h`](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/shared/ntstatus.h) or in [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55). Or you can use these two sites for looking up the error code for you: [1](https://errorcodelookup.com/) [2](https://errorco.de/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the subprocess needed one dll, which was in another folder and loaded into the game, but the subprocess did not see it